# Why does jQuery validation plugin configuration override after initialisation not work?

Tags: jquery, validation

i am trying to set up form validation with [this jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/). My plan is to load page with an initially configured validation object and reset its configuration to my needs when ever required. But it does not work as expected. After initialisation it doesn't accept a new configuration object. Here is my code:

```
<form id="testform">
   <input type="text" name="myField" value="" id="myFieldID" class="myFieldClass" placeholder="Type something..." title="Please fill myField" />
   <input type="submit" class="validate" name="submit" value="Test"/>
</form>

<script>
var validator = $('#testform').validate({debug: true});

validator = $('#testform').validate({
   debug: false,
   rules: {
      myField : "required"
   },
   messages: {
      myField : "Hello Other!"
   }
});
</script>
```

After initialisation when dumping the validator object it keeps showing `debug: true` and no rules nor messages. [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ja5udsLo/) for a that.
I checked the author's docs up and down and searched this forum but cannot find a satisfying answer.

Somebody here can teach me/us why this way doesn't work and how to do it the right way, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was designed to only be configured once. It has a rules() method to change rules if that's all you want. However, it's storing a reference to the validator in the jquery data library. We can clear that reference out with `$('#testform').data('validator', null);`. This is tricking the script to run the setup again so test it to make sure it doesn't do anything crazy.

http://jsfiddle.net/bva07bk1/

Comment: The rules parameter is not the only parameter i need to override. Mostly when changing the rules the messages have to be changed too since they belong together. If your solution - which works by the way - is the only way to get it managed my approach, to have a somewhat global/master-like validator to be re-configured when required, appears to be wrong since its getting replaced by a brand new instance everytime i need to change the config. This is how i got you. Please correct me if i'm wrong! Do you see an easier, more effective way to achieve what i want?

Comment: What are the benefits of the master validator? Maybe there is another approach you could take.

Comment: I have a base configuration object which is stored in a separate javascript file. After i load the validator script file in my index.php i also load the validator.config and create a validator instance from it. Now, everytime when i load a form via AJAX i have to update the validator settings according to the form fields. The form received contains a small script block for the validator update. I don't want to load the validator and the config in every form template i send via AJAX. I'd rather do it once and update it to fit the new requirements. That's the plan ... at least. Any better idea?

Comment: Well technically it's just the config you're loading with each ajax form right? Not the whole validator script again. Then you can just call validator again with the new config?

Comment: You could also try and directly manipulate validator.settings. Briefly looking at the code, it should be ok.

Comment: In fact this is what i'd like to achive, but what doesn't work because `validator.validate(newconfig)`does not work. The new config is not applied, which is why you concluded the plugin to be designed to be configured only once. My jsfiddle should reflect this issue. The first `validate()` is the initialisation. The second one simulates the reconfig after AJAX done. It doesn't work.